# How to rearrange item of an array to new position in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Consider the array `[1,2,3,4]`. How can I rearrange the array item to new position.

For example:

`put 3 into position 4 [1,2,4,3]`

`put 4 in to position 1 [4,1,2,3]`

`put 2 into position 3 [1,3,2,4]`.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

### Swift 3.0+:

```
let element = arr.remove(at: 3)
arr.insert(element, at: 2)
```

and in function form:

```
func rearrange<T>(array: Array<T>, fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) -> Array<T>{
    var arr = array
    let element = arr.remove(at: fromIndex)
    arr.insert(element, at: toIndex)

    return arr
}
```

### Swift 2.0:

This puts 3 into position 4.

```
let element = arr.removeAtIndex(3)
arr.insert(element, atIndex: 2)
```

You can even make a general function:

```
func rearrange<T>(array: Array<T>, fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) -> Array<T>{
    var arr = array
    let element = arr.removeAtIndex(fromIndex)
    arr.insert(element, atIndex: toIndex)

    return arr
}
```

The `var` `arr` is needed here, because you can't mutate the input parameter without specifying it to be `in-out`. In our case however we get a pure functions with no side effects, which is a lot easier to reason with, in my opinion.
You could then call it like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
rearrange(arr, fromIndex: 2, toIndex: 0) //[3,1,2,4]
```

Comment: Does swift handle this kind of remove and insert efficiently?

Comment: For most cases, yes, if you do it a LOT, it might give you some issues, but I wouldn't worry about it, unless it's a  real bottleneck in your app :)

Comment: Shouldn't this last line read fromIndex:2 ?. 3 is the 3rd element at the SECOND index

Comment: There's a typo in the Swift 3.0+ solution: you left the 3 and 2 hardcoded in the body :)

Comment: Isn't the solution here flawed for the case where the toIndex is greater than the fromIndex as the removeAtIndex will change the Index of the destination toIndex point?

Comment: would be nice to add a check in the function either the fromIndex and toIndex array contained in the given array

Answer (score 77):

All great answers! Here's a more complete **Swift 5** solution with performance in mind and bonus for benchmark and GIF fans. ✌️

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable
{
    mutating func move(_ element: Element, to newIndex: Index) {
        if let oldIndex: Int = self.firstIndex(of: element) { self.move(from: oldIndex, to: newIndex) }
    }
}

extension Array
{
    mutating func move(from oldIndex: Index, to newIndex: Index) {
        // Don't work for free and use swap when indices are next to each other - this
        // won't rebuild array and will be super efficient.
        if oldIndex == newIndex { return }
        if abs(newIndex - oldIndex) == 1 { return self.swapAt(oldIndex, newIndex) }
        self.insert(self.remove(at: oldIndex), at: newIndex)
    }
}
```

[image: GIF]

Comment: The documentation says: "Calling swapAt(_:_:) with the same index as both i and j has no effect." I think that means that the line `if oldIndex == newIndex { return }` is not needed here. EDIT: Okay, I thought again. If you keep the line, `abs(newIndex - oldIndex)` isn't unnecessarily calculated.

Comment: Can someone explain why not use `swapAt` for all cases rather than only for when they are side by side. Is using `insert/remove` a better solution for those cases?

Comment: Consider `[A, B, C, D]`. Moving item at index `3` to `0` gives you `[D, A, B, C]`. Swapping item at index `3` to `0` gives you `[D, B, C, A]`.

Comment: Thank you, this explains it so swap "changes" the entire array rather than the two positions.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov: As the name implies, `swapAt` swaps two elements. This is equivalent to removing both elements A and B and then inserting A at the position where B used to be and B at the position where A was before the swap.


`[w, A, x, y, B, z].swapAt(1, 4)` would result in `[w, B, x, y, A, z]`, with the positions of  A and B swapped and those of the other elements (w, x, y and z) unchanged.

Comment: Doesn't this solution also have the problem that moving to the "right" inserts 1 element too far to the right? Assuming I have the array `abc = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]` and use `abc.move("D", to: 5)`, I would expect the `"D"` to be inserted at position 5 (that is, the position of the `"F"`). But the result is `["A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "D", "G"]`. So it is inserted after the `"F"`.

Comment: Running benchmarks in Playground shall not be trusted. Please run benchmarks in XCTests instead.

Answer (score 49):

edit/update: **Swift 3.x**

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Indices: Equatable {
    mutating func rearrange(from: Index, to: Index) {
        precondition(from != to && indices.contains(from) && indices.contains(to), "invalid indices")
        insert(remove(at: from), at: to)
    }
}
```

---

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4]
numbers.rearrange(from: 1, to: 2)

print(numbers)  // [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: nice, for Swift 3:  
  
  
extension Array {  
 mutating func rearrange(from: Int, to: Int) {
  insert(remove(at: from), at: to)
 }
}


var myArray = [1,2,3,4]


myArray.rearrange(from: 1, to: 2)

print(myArray)

Comment: insert(remove...) what if element doesn't exist?

Comment: There is a  precondition

Comment: Isn't the solution here flawed for the case where the toIndex is greater than the fromIndex as the removeAtIndex will change the Index of the destination toIndex point?

Comment: Leo, my point really is that if this is called with, for example, array.rearrange(from: 5, to: 2) it would correctly remove item 5 and insert it before item 2. If however we try array.rearrange(from: 2, to: 5) it would remove item 2, adjusting the index of all items after item 2 and then insert before item 6. I just feel this is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It checks both indexes to make sure it can remove and insert the elements. check the insert method description **The new element is inserted before the element currently at the specified index. If you pass the collection’s endIndex property as the index parameter, the new element is appended to the collection.**. Btw why are you concerned about something that works as expected?

Comment: Leo, it seemed to me that there would be a side effect of the Remove operation that would influence how the function works depending on whether you are moving an item forwards or backwards. It does appear however that I am wrong in this.

Comment: Nice tip, I just don't know if it should be that strict to throw error if go and from are the same, I think it should just return, so I have added guard from != to else { return }. My case for using this for moving table view cells, and since you could put cell back, I don't want for app to crash. :) So I did a little change. :)))

Comment: its crashing `specialized RangeReplaceableCollection<>.rearrange(from:to:) + 19 (Array+Index.swift:19) ` Not good.

Answer (score 30):

nice tip from Leo.

for Swift 3...5.5:

```
extension Array {  
    mutating func rearrange(from: Int, to: Int) {
        insert(remove(at: from), at: to)
    }
}

var myArray = [1,2,3,4]
myArray.rearrange(from: 1, to: 2)   
print(myArray)
```

Answer (score 27):

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

// Swap elements at index: 2 and 3
print(arr)
arr.swapAt(2, 3)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Short and sweet answer!

Answer (score 20):

### Swift 5

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func move(_ item: Element, to newIndex: Index) {
        if let index = index(of: item) {
            move(at: index, to: newIndex)
        }
    }
    
    mutating func bringToFront(item: Element) {
        move(item, to: 0)
    }
    
    mutating func sendToBack(item: Element) {
        move(item, to: endIndex-1)
    }
}

extension Array {
    mutating func move(at index: Index, to newIndex: Index) {
        insert(remove(at: index), at: newIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use swap method to swap items in an array :

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

// Swap elements at index: 2 and 3
print(arr)
swap(&arr[2], &arr[3])
print(arr)
```

Comment: My question is how to rearrange the item not swap 2 items.

Comment: both are the same as you want to move items from one index to other and swap is a better way i guess.

Comment: Um. [1,2,3,4,5] swapping 3 and 5 will have [1,2,5,4,3] but I want is [1,2,4,5,3] which is move item at index 2 into index 4

Comment: then its simple just do like : `let element = arr.removeAtIndex(2)` & `arr.append(element)`

Answer (score 2):

@ian has provided good solution but it will be crash when array become out of bound added check for that too

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    public mutating func move(_ element: Element, to newIndex: Index) {
        if let oldIndex: Int = index(of: element) {
            self.move(from: oldIndex, to: newIndex)
        }
    }

    public mutating func moveToFirst(item: Element) {
        self.move(item, to: 0)
    }

    public mutating func move(from oldIndex: Index, to newIndex: Index) {
        // won't rebuild array and will be super efficient.
        if oldIndex == newIndex { return }
        // Index out of bound handle here
        if newIndex >= self.count { return }
        // Don't work for free and use swap when indices are next to each other - this
        if abs(newIndex - oldIndex) == 1 { return self.swapAt(oldIndex, newIndex) }
        // Remove at old index and insert at new location
        self.insert(self.remove(at: oldIndex), at: newIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no move functionality in swift for arrays. you can take an object at an index by removing it from there and place it in your favourite index by using 'insert'

```
var swiftarray = [1,2,3,4]
let myobject = swiftarray.removeAtIndex(1) // 2 is the object at 1st index
let myindex = 3
swiftarray.insert(myobject, atIndex: myindex) // if you want to insert the    object to a particular index here it is 3
swiftarray.append(myobject) // if you want to move the object to last index
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** - Solution for moving a group of items from an `IndexSet` of indices, grouping them and moving them to a destination index.  Realised through an extension to `RangeReplaceableCollection`.  Includes a method to remove and return all items in an `IndexSet`.  I wasn't sure how to constrain the extension to a more generalised form than to constrain the element than integer while maintaining the ability to construct `IndexSets` as my knowledge of Swift Protocols is not that extensive.

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self.Indices.Element == Int {

    /**
        Removes the items contained in an `IndexSet` from the collection.
        Items outside of the collection range will be ignored.

        - Parameter indexSet: The set of indices to be removed.
        - Returns: Returns the removed items as an `Array<Self.Element>`.
    */
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeItems(in indexSet: IndexSet) -> [Self.Element] {

        var returnItems = [Self.Element]()

        for (index, _) in self.enumerated().reversed() {
            if indexSet.contains(index) {
                returnItems.insert(self.remove(at: index), at: startIndex)
            }
        }
        return returnItems
    }


    /**
        Moves a set of items with indices contained in an `IndexSet` to a     
        destination index within the collection.

        - Parameters:
            - indexSet: The `IndexSet` of items to move.
            - destinationIndex: The destination index to which to move the items.
        - Returns: `true` if the operation completes successfully else `false`.

        If any items fall outside of the range of the collection this function 
        will fail with a fatal error.
    */
    @discardableResult
    mutating func moveItems(from indexSet: IndexSet, to destinationIndex: Index) -> Bool {

        guard indexSet.isSubset(of: IndexSet(indices)) else {
            debugPrint("Source indices out of range.")
            return false
            }
        guard (0..<self.count + indexSet.count).contains(destinationIndex) else {
            debugPrint("Destination index out of range.")
            return false
        }

        let itemsToMove = self.removeItems(in: indexSet)

        let modifiedDestinationIndex:Int = {
            return destinationIndex - indexSet.filter { destinationIndex > $0 }.count
        }()

        self.insert(contentsOf: itemsToMove, at: modifiedDestinationIndex)

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with functions to both change the array in-place and to return a changed array:

```
extension Array {
    func rearranged(from fromIndex: Int, to toIndex: Int) -> [Element] {
        var arr = self
        let element = arr.remove(at: fromIndex)
        
        if toIndex >= self.count {
            arr.append(element)
        } else {
            arr.insert(element, at: toIndex)
        }
        return arr
    }
    
    mutating func rearrange(from fromIndex: Int, to toIndex: Int) {
        let element = self.remove(at: fromIndex)
        if toIndex >= self.count {
            self.append(element)
        } else {
            self.insert(element, at: toIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.remove()` will change the array, so `toIndex` will not necessarily point to the same item as before calling `rearrange()`. Depends on whether `fromIndex` is greater or smaller than `toIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

Since macOS 10.15, iOS 14, `MutableCollection` has the method  `move(fromOffsets:toOffset:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/move(fromoffsets:tooffset:)

Comment: I wonder if the implementation of that API is buggy or intentional: `values.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 2), toOffset: 2)` and `values.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 2), toOffset: 3)` give the same result. Which doesn't make sense to me. Looks like if toOffset comes after fromOffset everything is shifter by 1 than what I expect would happen.

Comment: toOffset is relative to the initial state of the array, so this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't make it clear for me. If you have `var values = Array(0...5)` and then do `values.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 2), toOffset: 2)` and `values.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 2), toOffset: 3)` in both cases the array remains the same (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`).  Only in the first case I would have expected it to stay the same, in the second case I was expecting `[0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5]`. Additionally, the behaviour is different from the sample codes from the upvoted answers.

Comment: Imagine inserting a copy, then removing the original. You should see a difference if you move a higher index to a lower one.

Comment: Right, interesting, cheers for the explanation! Everyone above has been removing first and then inserting. IMO, the API should come with an extra parameter that takes enum values called `policy:` or something.

Comment: This API is very confusing. Why do we need IndexSet?

Answer (score 0):

> Update with Swift 4,
>   Swipe array index

```
for (index,addres) in self.address.enumerated() {
     if addres.defaultShipping == true{
          let defaultShipping = self.address.remove(at: index)
          self.address.insert(defaultShipping, at: 0)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient solution:

```
extension Array 
{
    mutating func move(from sourceIndex: Int, to destinationIndex: Int)
    {
        guard
            sourceIndex != destinationIndex
            && Swift.min(sourceIndex, destinationIndex) >= 0
            && Swift.max(sourceIndex, destinationIndex) < count
        else {
            return
        }

        let direction = sourceIndex < destinationIndex ? 1 : -1
        var sourceIndex = sourceIndex

        repeat {
            let nextSourceIndex = sourceIndex + direction
            swapAt(sourceIndex, nextSourceIndex)
            sourceIndex = nextSourceIndex
        }
        while sourceIndex != destinationIndex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func adjustIndex(_ index: Int, forRemovalAt removed: Int) -> Int {
    return index <= removed ? index : index - 1
}

extension Array
{
    mutating func move(from oldIndex: Index, to newIndex: Index) {
        insert(remove(at: oldIndex), at: adjustIndex(newIndex, forRemovalAt: oldIndex))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 Tested**

Just to add extra toppings on cake,
I've added functionality to handle `Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>`

Main Source of my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50205000/4131763,

here is my version,

```
//Array+Extension.swift,
extension Array where Element: Equatable
{
    mutating func move(_ element: Element, to newIndex: Index) {
        if let oldIndex: Int = self.firstIndex(of: element) { self.move(from: oldIndex, to: newIndex) }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Dictionary<String, Any> {
    
    mutating func move(_ element:Element, to newIndex: Index) {
        if let oldIndex = self.firstIndex(where: { ($0.keys.first ?? "") == (element.keys.first ?? "") }) {
            self.move(from: oldIndex, to: newIndex)
        }
    }
}

extension Array
{
    mutating func move(from oldIndex: Index, to newIndex: Index) {
        // Don't work for free and use swap when indices are next to each other - this
        // won't rebuild array and will be super efficient.
        if oldIndex == newIndex { return }
        if abs(newIndex - oldIndex) == 1 { return self.swapAt(oldIndex, newIndex) }
        self.insert(self.remove(at: oldIndex), at: newIndex)
    }
}
```

**HOW TO USE,**

```
if let oldIndex = array.firstIndex(where: { ($0["ValidationTitle"] as! String) == "MEDICALNOTICEREQUIRED" }) {
                    let obj = array[oldIndex]
                    array.move(obj, to: array.startIndex)
                }
                
                if let oldIndex = array.firstIndex(where: { ($0["ValidationTitle"] as! String) == "HIGHRISKCONFIRMATION" }) {
                    let obj = array[oldIndex]
                    let oldIndexMEDICALNOTICEREQUIRED = array.firstIndex(where: { ($0["ValidationTitle"] as! String) == "MEDICALNOTICEREQUIRED" })!
                    array.move(obj, to: oldIndexMEDICALNOTICEREQUIRED + 1)
                }
                
                if let oldIndex = array.firstIndex(where: { ($0["ValidationTitle"] as! String) == "UNLICENCEDCONFIRMATION" }) {
                    let obj = array[oldIndex]
                    let oldIndexHIGHRISKCONFIRMATION = array.firstIndex(where: { ($0["ValidationTitle"] as! String) == "HIGHRISKCONFIRMATION" })!
                    array.move(obj, to: oldIndexHIGHRISKCONFIRMATION + 1)
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Leo Dabus's solution is great however using precondition(from != to && indices.contains(from != to && indices.contains(to), "invalid indexes"), will crash the app if the conditions are not met. I changed it to guard and an if statement - if for some reason the conditions are not met, nothing happens and the app continues. I think we should avoid making extensions that may crash the app. If you wish you could make the rearrange function return a Bool - true if successful and false if failed.
**The safer solution:**

```
extension Array {
mutating func rearrange(from: Int, to: Int) {
    guard from != to else { return }
    //precondition(from != to && indices.contains(from) && indices.contains(to), "invalid indexes")
    if indices.contains(from) && indices.contains(to) {
        insert(remove(at: from), at: to)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer. Why is this safer?

Comment: Leo, Thank you for the link, very informative. I admit to not fully understanding the use of preconditions and asserts and the link clarifies some of this for me. For my own use, I needed the rearrange function to not crash the app even if the array did not contain the indices, but just leave the array as is.

Answer (score -1):

How about this solution?
The element to be changed and the element to be changed have been changed.

```
// Extenstion

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  mutating func change(_ element: Element, to newIndex: Index) {
    if let firstIndex = self.firstIndex(of: element) {
      self.insert(element, at: 0)
      self.remove(at: firstIndex + 1)
    }
  }
}

// Example

var testArray = ["a", "b", "c", "EE", "d"]
testArray.change("EE", to: 0)

// --> Result
// ["EE", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is incorrect. 2 issues -> You haven't used "newIndex" variable; you need to remove element before you insert -> This is because newindex can be  before or after the existing index (when you do (`firstindex +1`) you are assuming that the newIndex < firstIndex)

Answer (score -2):

Function(not swift but universal..  lookup/remove/insert):

```
func c_move_to(var array:Array,var from:Int,var to:Int):

    var val = array[from]
    array.remove(from)
    array.insert(to,val)
    return array
```

How to use:

```
print("MOVE 0 to 3  [1,2,3,4,5]"  , c_move_to([1,2,3,4,5],0,3))
print("MOVE 1 to 2  [1,2,3,4,5]"  , c_move_to([1,2,3,4,5],1,2))
```

spits out:

```
MOVE 0 to 3  [1,2,3,4,5][2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
MOVE 1 to 2  [1,2,3,4,5][1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You state universal, not swift. So why post? doesn't answer the OP's question. Much better Swift answers already posted (`array.swap(...)`)